# Win32 API SetTimer in a loop

Tags: winapi

is it possible to have a SetTimer() function inside a loop? Inside WM_TIMER I have a KillTimer() function and it prematurelly ends the loop for SetTimer(). Here's a bit of code, which should draw vertical lines every second with a 10 point incrementation in their X coordinate. Once I reach the end of the dialog box, SetTimer() should be called again but this time all new lines need to be 1 point to the right of the previous ones. This loop happens 10 times and it should make the whole width of the dialog box in random colors.

```
int x5 = 0 ; int y5 = 10; int y6 = 100; //DrawTimer points global variables
int n=0 //counter global variable

INT_PTR CALLBACK DrawTimer(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    else if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_START)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            SetTimer(hDlg,1,1000,NULL);
            x5 = 0;
            i++;
            x5+=i;
            if(i == 10)
                break;
        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        switch(wParam)
        {
            case 1:
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc;
                hdc = BeginPaint(hDlg, &ps);
                HPEN hPen;
                HGDIOBJ hObj;
                RECT rcClient;
                int diff;
                GetClientRect(hDlg, &rcClient);
                diff = rcClient.right - rcClient.left;
                int r = rand()%255;
                int g = rand()%255;
                int b = rand()%255;
                hdc = GetDC(hDlg);
                hPen = CreatePen(NULL,1,RGB(r,g,b));
                hObj = SelectObject(hdc,hPen);
                MoveToEx(hdc,x5,y5,NULL);
                LineTo(hdc,x5,y6);
                x5+=10;
                n++;
                SetDlgItemInt(hDlg,ID_COUNT,n,NULL);
                if (x5 > diff)
                KillTimer(hDlg,1);
                EndPaint(hDlg, &ps);
        }
        break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't how it works at all. You still need to make that mind shift from classic linear style console mode programming to event driven callback based programming.

Comment: You will also need to learn that painting and timers are separate on Windows; you have to have your timers schedule a paint event, where you will do your painting.